# How to format/Scrub Source data for Import into SQL Server SSNs and Phone Numbers

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, dml

Due to my database storing formatted data for SSNs and Phone numbers I am in need of methods to first take the incoming data regardless of it's formatting and format it to match how my database stores data in these fields.  The data for which I'm migrating is temporarily imported by the Application by an end user from a external application into a Temp Table to then be refactored and manipulated for INSERT into my Client Database.

I'm having issues working with data without Regular Expressions.  How does one accomplish DML tasks like these in SQL Server?  The desired output for my two data types are below.  I'm struggling with getting my source data into these output formats.

**Data Storage Desired Output Format for Insert**

> SSN: 123-45-6789
>
> SSN: IF 8 chars then pad with leading zero
>
> SSN: IF less than 8 chars then pad with question mark '?'... ???-??-1234 (Don't ask )
>
> Phones: 123-456-7890

**Sample Code**

```
WITH fakeCSVData AS
(
    SELECT '111223333' AS SSN, '(444) 4444444'  AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '211222121' AS SSN, '101 232-4545'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '12334556'  AS SSN, '(191) 330-4345' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '41531'     AS SSN, '(039) 084-8309' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '220981278' AS SSN, '(298) 372-9234' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '222013450' AS SSN, '(78) 909-7790'  AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '123456789' AS SSN, '(717)_272-7277' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '113344556' AS SSN, '210-973-2123'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '808768252' AS SSN, '(219) 362-1895' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '3456'      AS SSN, '895 536-5356'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '204874556' AS SSN, '(909) 544-9124' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '80832934'  AS SSN, '0271932132'     AS Phone


)

SELECT 


    CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn))           LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn))
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn))          LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'      THEN RIGHT( REPLICATE('0', 1) + LTRIM(RTRIM( csv.ssn )), 11)
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn))          LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'   THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),1,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),4,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),6,4)
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn))          LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'        THEN RIGHT( REPLICATE('0', 1) + LTRIM(RTRIM( SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),3,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),5,4) )), 11)
            WHEN RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),4) LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'                           THEN '???-??-' + RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(csv.ssn)),4)
      END AS SocSecNo
    , NullIf(LEFT( REPLACE( LTRIM(RTRIM( REPLACE(REPLACE(csv.Phone, ')', ''), '(', '') )), ' ' , '-') , 12), '') AS Phone


FROM fakeCSVData csv
```

**Current Output of Sample Code**

```
SocSecNo    | Phone
--------------------------
111-22-3333 | 444-4444444
211-22-2121 | 101-232-4545
012-33-4556 | 191-330-4345
???-??-1531 | 039-084-8309
220-98-1278 | 298-372-9234
222-01-3450 | 78-909-7790
123-45-6789 | 717_272-7277
???-??-4556 | 210-973-2123
808-76-8252 | 219-362-1895
???-??-3456 | 895-536-5356
204-87-4556 | 909-544-9124
080-83-2934 | 0271932132
```

I keep thinking that if I just had a simple method to first remove all non-numeric characters from the incoming source data that I could then just format the string as I need it to be formatted... but I'm not finding any SQL Server Native functions that do this.

Answer (score 1):

A little ugly, but perhaps this will help

```
WITH fakeCSVData AS
(
    SELECT '111223333' AS SSN, '(444) 4444444'  AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '211222121' AS SSN, '101 232-4545'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '12334556'  AS SSN, '(191) 330-4345' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '41531'     AS SSN, '(039) 084-8309' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '220981278' AS SSN, '(298) 372-9234' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '222013450' AS SSN, '(78) 909-7790'  AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '123456789' AS SSN, '(717)_272-7277' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '113344556' AS SSN, '210-973-2123'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '808768252' AS SSN, '(219) 362-1895' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '3456'      AS SSN, '895 536-5356'   AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '204874556' AS SSN, '(909) 544-9124' AS Phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '80832934'  AS SSN, '0271932132'     AS Phone
)

Select NewSSN = format(try_convert(bigint,SSN),choose(len(SSN)
                                               ,'???-??-???0'
                                               ,'???-??-??00'
                                               ,'???-??-?000'
                                               ,'???-??-0000'
                                               ,'???-?0-0000'
                                               ,'???-00-0000'
                                               ,'??0-00-0000'
                                               ,'?00-00-0000'
                                               ,'000-00-0000') )
      ,NewPhn = format(try_convert(bigint,Phn),choose(len(Phn)
                                               ,'???-???-???0'
                                               ,'???-???-??00'
                                               ,'???-???-?000'
                                               ,'???-???-0000'
                                               ,'???-??0-0000'
                                               ,'???-?00-0000'
                                               ,'???-000-0000'
                                               ,'??0-000-0000'
                                               ,'?00-000-0000'
                                               ,'000-000-0000') )
 From fakeCSVData A
 Cross Apply ( values (  replace(
                         replace(
                         replace(
                         replace(
                         replace(Phone,' ','') 
                         ,'(','')
                         ,')','')
                         ,'-','')
                         ,'_','')
                      )
             ) B(Phn)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**EDIT**

You may notice the `CROSS APPLY` will clean-up the `PHONE` string.  This may require some maintenance or even a UDF to strip non-numeric values.